# Convert a bitarray to integer in Python

Tags: python

I've been searching for methods to convert a bitarray into integer. Now I'm using this code:

```
def bin2int(bin_array):
    int_ = 0
    for bit in bin_array:
        int_ = (int_ << 1) | bit
    return int_
```

where bin_array is a bitarray randomly filled.
I'm curios about other methods that you know of, like functions from bitarray or numpy...

Comment: Just out of interest: how do you know that this is the *quickest* way?

Comment: I don't, that's the point

Comment: Ah, in that case the title shouldn't make that claim.  I've edited.

Comment: Here's a numpy version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791312/numpy-packbits-pack-to-uint16-array

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in [bitarray.util](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray#functions-defined-in-bitarrayutil-module) called `ba2int`:

```py
from bitarray import bitarray
from bitarray.util import ba2int

ba = bitarray('1001')  # 9

i = ba2int(ba)

print(f'Value: {i} type: {type(i)}')
# Output: Value: 9 type: <class 'int'>
```

From the doc:

> ba2int(bitarray, /, signed=False) -> int
>
> Convert the given bitarray into an integer. The bit-endianness of the
> bitarray is respected. signed indicates whether two's complement is
> used to represent the integer.